# Resize large portion of images (any language or software)

Tags: windows

We recently decided to redesign our old app which used 150x150 thumbnails. New thumbs are of size 250x250.

Now what i have to do is an one-off process to replace all the old 150 thumbs that were created before the redesign, with 250 ones.

The function used for creating new thumbnails was php's `imagecopyresampled`. I would like to find something that would give me similar/same results.

> imagecopyresampled() copies a rectangular portion of one image to
>   another image, smoothly interpolating pixel values so that, in
>   particular, reducing the size of an image still retains a great deal
>   of clarity.

Also, the job itself is a little complicated since there are some folders/files that has to be excluded when iterating trough the files.

**Structure:**

```
level 1: company folder
level 2: company property folder, company products folder
level 3: there are images that have to be resized inside company property folder.
```

**Structure sample:**

```
company 1
company 2
company 3
----company 3 property
--------image1.jpg (original size)
--------image1_thumb.jpg (old 150 thumb)
--------image2.jpg
--------image2_thumb.jpg
----company 3 products (folder also includes images but they should not be resized)
```

Basically the only files we work with are original-sized images (ones without _thumb) inside property folders. Old 150px thumb images are to be deleted and/or replaced by new, 250px ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FvD says, ImageMagick is very good for resizing images.

For finding all the relevant files and having `convert` process them, I would suggest installing [findutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm), or even better [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), because the latter not only includes findutils but a whole lot of other goodies (like a proper shell) as well.

If you have Python installed, you could write a simple program that uses `os.walk()` to travel a file system tree and use `subprocess.call()` to `convert` the file.

A partial example;

```
import os
import subprocess

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('company 3\company 3 property'):
    images = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files if f.endswith('.jpg') and not '_thumb' in f]
    for f in images:
        outbase = f[:-4] # simply remove '.jpg'
        out = outbase += '_thumb.jpg'
        args = ['convert', f, '-scale', '250x250', out]
        subprocess.call(args)
```

**Edit**: If you have a directory that you don't want to visit, just remove it from the `dirs` dictionary. See the [documentation for `os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: I decided to use a Wand for image transformation. I will accept this answer because it gave me an idea how to start, but does not completely solve my question since there are more levels of folders to loop through, not only one like in your example. Also there are some folders that should be excluded from the loop.

I described the problem to you here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431007/create-thumbnails-for-images-inside-specific-folders

Comment: @BikerJohn You can skip directories in `os.walk`. See edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can set up the traversal through the folders with anything you like. The conversion is best done with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) that works greate from the commandline or embedded into anything else.

The particular magic you are looking for is under [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).